# Yii smtp mail sending fails for office365 host

Tags: yii, smtp

While sending mail from YII, for smtp protocol, it gives below error:

```
Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [BM1PR01CA0097.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] " in /var/www/html/vvf.kritva.in/protected/extensions/yii-mail/vendors/swiftMailer/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:406
```

Even if port change to 587, it gives same error.

```
'transportType' => 'smtp', 
'transportOptions' => array( 
        'host'=>'smtp.office365.com', 
        'username'=>'xyz@xyz.com', 
        'password'=>'password', 
        'port'=>'587', 
     // 'encryption' => 'tls' 
 ),
```

The code in controller is as below :

```
    $message = new YiiMailMessage;
    $message->setBody('Message content here with HTML', 'text/html');
    $message->subject = 'xyz';
    $message->addTo('xyz@xyz.com');
    $message->from = 'xyz@xyz.com';
    Yii::app()->mail->send($message);
```

Please help to rectify this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check my code is as follow :'transportType'=>'smtp',
        'transportOptions'=>array(
          'host'=>'smtp.office365.com',
                    'username'=>'username',
                    'password'=>'password',
                    'port'=>'587',
                    // 'encryption' => 'tls'
        ),

Comment: Hello there, please provide code how you send this email.

Comment: I am sending mail using below code in yii :Yii::import('ext.yii-mail.YiiMailMessage');
  $message = new YiiMailMessage;
  $message->setBody('Message content here with HTML', 'text/html');
  $message->subject = 'Demo';
  $message->addTo('xyx@xyz.com');
  $message->from = 'xyx@xyz.com';
  try {
    Yii::app()->mail->send($message);
    return true;
  } catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
  }

Comment: Please put this code in your question by editting it.

Answer (score 0):

So main problem is this line:

```
$message->from = 'xyz@xyz.com';
```

You have to change this e-mail address to be exacly same as this registered in `office365.com`. If you created email called `monica@office365.com` then you have to put this as `from()` before sending.

Comment: Thats correct i have enter that in from address as well as in mail.php but it doesn't send mail so to try with other mailer i just test using phpmailer instead of YiiMailMessage the mail sending script is working.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue also, I could send from one account but not another, many times this is due to the fact that the account you are trying to send from is in a protected group, such as, administrators or printers.

Answer (score 0):

\config\web.php

```
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'enableSwiftMailerLogging' => true,
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',               
            'plugins' => 
            [
                [
                    'class' => 'Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin',
                    'constructArgs' => [new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger],
                ],
            ],
            'host' => 'smtp.office365.com',
            'authMode' => 'login',
            'username' => 'your email id',
            'password' => 'your password',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
    ],
```

////////////use this function to send mail/////////////

```
public function sendemail($from,$to,$subject,$content)
 { 
    try{
        $mailCompose = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->setTo($to);
        $mailCompose->setBcc($bccEmailIds);
        $mailCompose->setSubject($subject)
            ->setHtmlBody($content)
            ->send();
            $msg = 'Email sent';
    }catch(Exception  $e){
        $msg = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```